# how can I detect if singleTap was tapped or annotation on mapView of mapbox?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox, mapbox-gl

**Requirment on iOS for mapBox map.** (I am not talking about MKMapView)
how can we detect if singleTap was tapped or annotation on mapView? I need that singleTap will be handled only on empty area of map (without pins), and didSelectAnnotation called when i tap on pin.

But I found on android we have method like this

```
mapboxMap.setOnMapClickListener(new MapboxMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            public void onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng point) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"on Tap "+point.getLatitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

and along with that

`mapboxMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MapboxMap.InfoWindowAdapter() { ... })` will display the annotation.

Don't we have same kind of concept in iOS ?

The actual problem is in iOS is, when I add `singleTapGesture` on **mapView of Mapbox**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGesture];
```

the delegate method of **mapView of mapbox** will not call.

```
- (nullable UIView <MGLCalloutView> *)mapView:(MGLMapView *)mapView calloutViewForAnnotation:(id <MGLAnnotation>)annotation;
```

to make sure the delegate method must call, then I dont have to use `singleTapGesture`

Here the situation is either this or that, but as per me need I needed both.

Looking forward of any solution.
Thanks,

Comment: INasir show me your full coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made another workaround here

I cloned the **release-ios-v3.3.0** and created package using [Building the SDK](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/e9dcfa0ed627ecb8783d1ac7f38a24db51cf8cb8/platform/ios/DEVELOPING.md#building-the-sdk) and added one delegate method in 
`MGLMapvViewDelegate.h` 
as per my need something like that. 
`-(void)mapView:(MGLMapView *)mapView tapOnNonAnnotationAreaWithPoints:(CGPoint)points`

and in MGLMapView.mm I updated the code like that,

```
else{
if(self.selectedAnnotation)
      [self deselectAnnotation:self.selectedAnnotation animated:YES];
else if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(mapView:tapOnNonAnnotationAreaWithPoints:)])
      [self.delegate mapView:self tapOnNonAnnotationAreaWithPoints:tapPoint];
}
```

which is in `-(void)handleSingleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)singleTap`
 method.

Its working for me, as I am able to detect single tap on non annotation area. later I convert the passed `points` to geo coordinates, so that I work with newly tapped coordinate.

**Note**

1. Newly Created library size is about `48.7 MB` where as downloaded library was `38.3 MB`.
2. Style is not working properly, you can see in attached pic.[image][image] (Tried with different Style URL but none of it is same as previous)
3. I feel lack in App performance, Zooming and Panning is not smooth as the dynamic library gave by Mapbox guys.

I am still exploring. lemme know if you wanna me to check/explore.

Please accept this answer, if it is helpful.

Thank you,

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 7):

Subclass MGLMapView and delegate its' `touchesEnded`.

```
protocol MapViewTapDelegate: class {

    func mapViewTapped(withTouchLocation touchLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D)
}

class MapView: MGLMapView {

    weak var tapDelegate: MapViewTapDelegate?

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)

        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }

        let touchLocation = convert(touch.location(in: self), toCoordinateFrom: nil)

        tapDelegate?.mapViewTapped(withTouchLocation: touchLocation)
    }

}
```

As `touchesEnded` isn't triggered when `didSelect annotation` is called and vice versa, this is what you need.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MapView! {

        didSet {

            mapView.delegate = self; mapView.tapDelegate = self
        }
    }

}

extension ViewController: MGLMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didSelect annotation: MGLAnnotation) {

        print("didSelect annotationWithCoordinate: \(annotation.coordinate)")
    }

}

extension ViewController: MapViewTapDelegate {

    func mapViewTapped(withTouchLocation touchLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

        print("mapViewTapped touchLocation: \(touchLocation)")
    }

}
```

Comment: There is an error on this setup when "mapView.tapDelegate = self" Cannot assign value of type 'UIViewController' to type 'MapViewTapDelegate?'

Answer (score 2):

I think that the method 
`-(void)mapView:(MGLMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotation:(id<MGLAnnotation>)annotation` will solve your problem for selecting annotation.

Comment: `-(void)mapView:(MGLMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotation:(id<MGLAnnotation>)annotation` will work when callout tapped only, but when I add `tapGesture` the on mapView none of delegate method works. In my case I need both `tapGesture` and `delegate` calls

Answer (score 1):

**Try swift 3**

```
//determined is Point inner to realm polygons
func determinedInPoligon(point:CLLocationCoordinate2D, poligon:[CLLocationCoordinate2D]) -> Bool {

    var result:Bool = false
    var j = poligon.count - 1

    for i in 0 ..< poligon.count {

        if  (poligon[i].longitude < point.longitude && poligon[j].longitude >= point.longitude || poligon[j].longitude < point.longitude && poligon[i].longitude >= point.longitude) &&
            (poligon[i].latitude + (point.longitude - poligon[i].longitude) / (poligon[j].longitude - poligon[i].longitude) * (poligon[j].latitude - poligon[i].latitude) < point.latitude) {
            result = !result;
        }
        j = i;

    }
    return result
}

func squareFrom(location: CGPoint, radius: Double) -> CGRect {//return rect with CGPoint center and radius
    let length = radius
    return CGRect(x: Double(location.x - CGFloat(length / 2)), y: 
   Double(location.y - CGFloat(length / 2)), width: length, height: length)
}
```

**function handle**

```
func handleTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    // Get the CGPoint where the user tapped.
    let spot = gesture.location(in: mapView)

    let my_features = mapView.visibleFeatures(at: spot)
    let strZoomValue = mapView.zoomLevel > 15 ? "6" : "4"
    //the feature structur object value not equal annotation object
    for value in my_features.enumerated() {// feature items
        if value.element is MGLPointAnnotation  {

            for annot in (mapView.annotations?.enumerated())! { // annotation items
                if annot.element is MGLPointAnnotation {

                    //rounded lat and lng value
                    var arr_cllocation = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
                    for cllocation in [(annot.element as! MGLPointAnnotation).coordinate, (value.element as! MGLPointAnnotation).coordinate] {

                        let strLat = String(format: "%."+strZoomValue+"f", cllocation.latitude)
                        let strLon = String(format: "%."+strZoomValue+"f", cllocation.longitude)
                        arr_cllocation.append(
                            CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(strLat)!, longitude: CLLocationDegrees(strLon)!) )
                    }

                    if arr_cllocation.count == 2 &&
                        memcmp(&arr_cllocation[0], &arr_cllocation[1], MemoryLayout<CLLocationCoordinate2D>.size) == 0 {// 0 if equal object
                        // to do custom popup view
                        let instViewPopupLineClass = UINib(nibName: "ViewPopupBase", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView

                        for objectInst in instViewPopupLineClass.subviews.enumerated() {

                            if objectInst.element is UILabel {
                                let asdasdas = (annot.element as! MGLPointAnnotation).subtitle
                                (objectInst.element as! UILabel).text = asdasdas
                                MyCustomPopup(customView: instViewPopupLineClass, positionXY: spot)
                                break
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } //for end

        }
    }
}
```

**OR not accurate method, but a worker ;)**

```
func handleTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {// Get the CGPoint where the user tapped.

    let spot = gesture.location(in: mapView)
    let cllcordinatTap = mapView.convert(spot, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
                 //for determined zoom scala
            let  deltScalaMap = abs(self.mapView.maximumZoomLevel - self.mapView.zoomLevel) 
           //The large is zoom maps, then smal size is tap location, and vice versa.
            let checkScalaMap = deltScalaMap == 0 ? 1 : deltScalaMap
            let _rect = squareFrom(location: CGPoint(x: cllcordinatTap.latitude, y: cllcordinatTap.longitude), radius: 0.00005 * checkScalaMap)
  for annot in (mapView.annotations?.enumerated())! {

       if annot.element is MGLPointAnnotation {
          let _cordinatCurrentAnnotation = (annot.element as! MGLPointAnnotation).coordinate

          if  determinedInPoligon(point: _cordinatCurrentAnnotation, poligon:
              [CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(_rect.minX), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(_rect.minY)),
               CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(_rect.maxX), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(_rect.minY)),
               CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(_rect.maxX), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(_rect.maxY)),
               CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(_rect.minX), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(_rect.maxY))
          ]) {

              // to do, if tap MGLPointAnnotation, annot.element

          }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I got some workaround which helped to work with my requirement.
As per my need I am able to get single tap detection on both **mapbox annotation marker** and as well as on **empty area of map**

I created category for MGLMapView, (*MGLMapView+EDCMapboxView*) and overrides the touch methods

```
-touchesBegan:withEvent:
-touchesMoved:withEvent:
-touchesEnded:withEvent:
-touchesCancelled:withEvent:
```

**MGLMapView+EDCMapboxView.h**

```
@protocol EDCMapboxViewDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)mapboxViewDidCreateNewTicket:(MGLMapView*)mapView;
@end

@interface MGLMapView (EDCMapboxView)

@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL shouldCreateNewTicket;

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <EDCMapboxViewDelegate> mapboxDelegate;
@end
```

**MGLMapView+EDCMapboxView.m**

```
@implementation MGLMapView (EDCMapboxView)
@dynamic mapboxDelegate;

#pragma mark -- Accessor
- (BOOL)shouldCreateNewTicket {
    return [objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(shouldCreateNewTicket)) boolValue];
}
- (void)setShouldCreateNewTicket:(BOOL)flag {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(shouldCreateNewTicket), @(flag), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(id<EDCMapboxViewDelegate>)mapboxDelegate{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(mapboxDelegate));
}
- (void)setMapboxDelegate:(id<EDCMapboxViewDelegate>)mapboxDelegate{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(mapboxDelegate), mapboxDelegate, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

#pragma mark -- Overrided method for UIResponder
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(nullable UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"touchesBegan");
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(nullable UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"touchesMoved");
    self.shouldCreateNewTicket = NO;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(nullable UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"touchesEnded");
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(nullable NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(nullable UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"touchesCancelled");

    [self createNewTicket];
}

- (void)createNewTicket{
    if(self.shouldCreateNewTicket){
        NSLog(@"Allowed to Create New ticket");
        // Tells that tap is on empty area.
        if([self.mapboxDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(mapboxViewDidCreateNewTicket:)]){
            [self.mapboxDelegate mapboxViewDidCreateNewTicket:self];
        }
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Not allowed to create New ticket");
        // Tells tap is on annotation marker.
        self.shouldCreateNewTicket = YES;
    }
}
```

**EDCMapboxViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mapView.shouldCreateNewTicket = YES;   
    .....
    .......
    ........
}

- (BOOL)mapView:(MGLMapView *)mapView annotationCanShowCallout:(id <MGLAnnotation>)annotation {
    NSLog(@"annotationCanShowCallout");

    // Tells that annotation is tapped, then do not allow to create ticket.
    self.mapView.shouldCreateNewTicket = NO;

    return YES;
}

- (void)mapboxViewDidCreateNewTicket:(MGLMapView*)mapView{
   // Tells that tap is on empty area and not on marker, then allow to create ticket. 
}
```

It worked for me, hope it will help you guys as well.
Thanks.

Comment: Here `shouldCreateNewTicket` flag will detect difference between **tap on empty area** and **tap on marker**.

Comment: Make sure that you must not end up by creating retain cycle. Update **MGLMapView+EDCMapboxView.m** category with

`OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN` instead of `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC `

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it, you should get the concept.

```
func onMapSingleTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    let viewLocation: CGPoint = recognizer.locationInView(map)

    // check if any annotations are hit
    if(map.annotations != nil)
    {
        for annotation in map.annotations!
        {
            if(annotation.isKindOfClass(MapCheckInAnnotation))
            {
                let pin: MapCheckInAnnotation = annotation as! MapCheckInAnnotation

                if let pinView = pin.view
                {
                    print("pinview \(pinView.frame.origin)")

                    // check if hit pin instead of just map
                    if(viewLocation.x >= pinView.frame.origin.x && viewLocation.x < pinView.frame.origin.x + pinView.frame.width)
                    {
                        if(viewLocation.y >= pinView.frame.origin.y && viewLocation.y < pinView.frame.origin.y + pinView.frame.height)
                        {
                            mapView(map, didSelectAnnotationView: pinView)
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // nope, no annotations were clicked
    let mapLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = map.convertPoint(viewLocation, toCoordinateFromView: map)

    print("onMapSingleTapped \(mapLocation)")

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried sample project for your question and it works well.

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapTapAnnotation;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


@synthesize mapTapAnnotation;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  [self setMapViewWithAnnnoationPin];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)setMapViewWithAnnnoationPin
{

  mapTapAnnotation.showsUserLocation = YES;
  mapTapAnnotation.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;

  CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(12.900988, 80.227930);

  MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.005,  0.005);
  MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};

  MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
  [annotation setCoordinate:coord];
  [annotation setTitle:@"Single Tap"]; //You can set the subtitle too


  [mapTapAnnotation setRegion:region];
  [mapTapAnnotation addAnnotation:annotation];


  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(detectSingleTap)];
  tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
  [mapTapAnnotation addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}

-(void)detectSingleTap
{
   NSLog(@"Finded the single tap on map view");
}


 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    NSLog(@"The single tap annotation pin point is - %ld",(long)view.tag);
}
```

The printed output results are

```
Finded the single tap on map view
The single tap annotation pin point is - 0
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help, But in my case MKMapView is not used, its MGLMapView (mapbox)

Comment: Upload your full coding

Comment: I have uploaded the files here http://jmp.sh/hUUviDX . It also consist of code of data fetching from CBL, Please ignore that, let me know anything more detail you need. Thank You.

Answer (score -1):

As I haven't been successful with the solutions above I implemented a small delay after the always recognized map tap event. If an annotation is selected in this small time frame, then nothing is called any further. Otherwise only the map view was tapped and no annotation.
Works pretty well in my case.

**MapView part**

```
 protocol MapDelegate: class { 
     func didTapMapView() 
 }

 class AppleMapView: MKMapView {

     weak var mapDelegate: MapDelegate?

     override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
             super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)

             if touches.first != nil {
                 mapDelegate?.didTapMapView()
             }
        }
        ........
}
```

**MapViewController part**

```
// property to store last tap at annotation
var lastAnnotationSelectionTime = Date()

// this method is called on every tap 
func didTapMapView() {
    let overlaySelectionDelayTime: TimeInterval = 0.2
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + overlaySelectionDelayTime, execute: { [weak self] in

         guard let self = self else { return }

         if self.lastAnnotationSelectionTime.distance(to: Date()) > overlaySelectionDelayTime {
                 // only called if no annotation was tapped meanwhile
                 [ HANDLE TAP ON MAP HERE ]
            }
         })
   }

// MARK: Marker Selection
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
     lastAnnotationSelectionTime = Date() // setten if annotation is tapped
     [ HANDLE TAP ON ANNOTATION HERE ]
}
```